# No such file or directory attach_file in django email

Tags: python, django, email, pdf

attach_file is not picking the absolute url although file exist. its able to pic internal url and send file but not the absolute url

```
email.attach_file("http://devuserapi.doctorinsta.com/static/pdfs/Imran_1066.pdf",mimetype="application/pdf")
```

this file opens when i copy paste the url in browser. what could be the issue.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`attach_file` takes a file from your filesystem, not a URL, so you have to use a local path to it

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/email/

One, untested, possibility is to use the `attach` method instead and to download the file on the fly:

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen("http://devuserapi.doctorinsta.com/static/pdfs/Imran_1066.pdf")
email.attach('IMran_1066.pdf',response.read(),mimetype="application/pdf")
```

It lacks error checking to make sure the file was downloaded, of course, and I haven't actually tried it myself, but that might be an alternative for you.

Comment: Is there any other way to attach the file from absolute url and send it in email. my pdfs are generated on different server and email is sent from different server

Comment: @ankushmadaan I think your options are likely to either embed a link to it instead of the file as an attachment; download the file, attach it, then remove it when done; or use the `attach` method and have the `content` argument be something that fetches the content "on the fly" so you don't have to store it on disk

Comment: will try one of the above things , but its very strange that we cant attach external attachments in django email. how people use CDN to send attach files ??

Comment: @ankushmadaan I'm not sure how others do it, but I updated my answer with a possible example of a work around for you